# Python Regular Expression: Replace Withing a group

Tags: python, regex, string-substitution

Is there a way to do substitution on a group?

Say I am trying to insert a link into text, based on custom formatting. So, given something like this:

```
This is a random text. This should be a [[link somewhere]]. And some more text at the end.
```

I want to end up with

```
This is a random text. This should be a <a href="/link_somewhere">link somewhere</a>. And some more text at the end.
```

I know that `'\[\[(.*?)\]\]'` will match stuff within square brackets as group 1, but then I want to do another substitution on group 1, so that I can replace space with `_`.

Is that doable in a single `re.sub` regex expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a function as a replacement instead of string.

```
>>> import re
>>> def as_link(match):
...     link = match.group(1)
...     return '<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(link.replace(' ', '_'), link)
...
>>> text = 'This is a random text. This should be a [[link somewhere]]. And some more text at the end.'
>>> re.sub(r'\[\[(.*?)\]\]', as_link, text)
'This is a random text. This should be a <a href="link_somewhere">link somewhere</a>. And some more text at the end.'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this.

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'\[\[([^]]+)\]\]')

def convert(text): 
    def replace(match):
        link = match.group(1)
        return '<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(link.replace(' ', '_'), link)
    return pattern.sub(replace, text)

s = 'This is a random text. This should be a [[link somewhere]]. .....'
convert(s)
```

See [working demo](https://eval.in/52952)

Comment: Yes, and I think this will not work if there are more than two words within the link.

Comment: Updated with better answer.